# React native Ctrl M or dev tool not showing in my emulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

He thanks in advance,
In react native am not able to right click or open dev mode in emulator.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70940672/debugger-options-not-open-when-ctrlm-in-android-studio-bumblebee-when-running-r

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

Use this in your windows command line, It works for me.

Comment: This work for some emulator and some android devices.
It works for me.

Comment: I'm sorry to see you didn't find a better solution, this would be way too annoying to type out everytime you need the dev menu.

Comment: @Hylle do you have a better workaround? You dont have to type each time. make the cmd open and hit the up arrow.

Comment: My more permanent workaround was to do a ./gradlew clean inside the android folder. Uninstall the app on phone, and run react-native run-android again. It seems to happen when I edited my AndroidManifest.xml file and added some native packages.

Comment: that just opens a widgets menu in the simulator

Comment: @JakeS then you can choose the Reload

Comment: 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @AljohnYamaro , you may have to add adb to your environment variables

Answer (score 1):

If the above solutions did not help, here is what worked for me.

1. Use an emulator that has Play Store installed. When creating a virtual device in Android Studio, it will have the Play Store icon.
2. Download Expo from the play store. For some reason, the Expo app that vscode pushes to my emulator won't work properly for me.
3. Run expo start and open the Expo Developer Tools page on your browser (by typing 'd' if it does not open automatically), and copy the url at the bottom left. Will look like `exp://127.0.0.1:19000` if you started with --localhost
4. On the emulator, run the expo app and on the top select `Open from Clipboard` and it will show the url you copied.

For me, this did a better job at starting the Building Javascript bundle, and once the app was loaded, I was able to use `Ctrl M` to mimic shaking the device and open the developer menu!

Other troubleshooting tips I learned while figuring this out:

- Like the comments above state, don't be in production mode
- Make sure to have paths set up correctly to be able to reach your Android sdk, nodejs, and your local project node_modules/bin if you are not doing global npm installs.
- If you are having issues with remote debugging, make sure the Chrome debugger is not open. Close it if it is open, have your debugger listening on the correct port (for me 19001) and reload the project on the device.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

FOR WINDOWS 10 YOU NEED TO ADD THIS SO THAT YOU CAN USE CRTL+M to open debug and reload

Add environment variables

Open a File Explorer, copy and paste the following into the address bar.

**Control Panel\System and Security\System**

Click on Advanced system settings on the left menu.

Click on Environmental Variables at the bottom.

Click on New to add a user variable (the top section).

You’ll be adding two:

Variable           Value
**ANDROID_HOME       C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk**

**JAVA_HOME          C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre**

Then under System variables (the bottom section), click on the Path variable and click on Edit.

On the pop-up window, click on New to add another variable:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools 
C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Click OK, OK

Then try your emulator
see this link: https://medium.com/@lpault29/react-native-environment-for-windows-e25806df867c

Comment: ganun parin walang ctrl+m :(

Comment: Thanks a lot! It also works without setting JAVA_HOME variable for the user. I have JAVA_HOME variable defined in system variables (pointed to java jdk), so I avoid this step trying not to mess things up.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off production mode solved my problem.

Comment: How to turn off production mode in react-native project?

Answer (score 0):

Expo solution:

I don't think it is the best way but this requires zero setup and works for me:

1. Go back to the expo terminal (The terminal where you entered `expo start`)
2. Press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd>
3. Choose `Toggle developer menu`

That's it, your emulator should appear the developer menu now.

Answer (score -1):

There is post which says turn off production mode -> it took me time to find in which settings -> I was looking in emulator settings, it was in expo-cli. This post is it clarify it.

1. Production mode off

In the expo-cli http://localhost:19002/, there is Production Mode (left side bar) -> turn it off

2. Open AVD Emulator and your application, press ctrl+M

It should work.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Make sure we installed all of these SDK files]
*Make sure we installed all of these SDK files,I tried all of the above solutions but no one solved my problem but everything is working now after doing this, hope it will solve your problem also