# Debugger Options Not open when ctrl+m in Android Studio Bumblebee when running react native app

Tags: react-native, android-studio, debugging, android-emulator

Debugger Options Not open when ctrl+m  in Android Studio Bumblebee when running react native app

Answer (score 16):

You will have to enable the emulator to run in a different window first, which would allow you to use the keyboard shortcuts

> To run the emulator in a separate window instead go to File > Settings
> Tools > Emulator (Android Studio > Preferences > Tools > Emulator on macOS) and deselect Launch in a tool window

Reference
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#run-emulator-studio

For mac os
[image]

Comment: This is the best answer. saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 4):

The root cause is the emulator launch in a tool window by default in Bumblebee.
To fix it by setting the emulator as a standalone application:

1. Android Studio > Preferences > Tools > Emulator (cmd + ',')
2. Deselete "Launch in a tool window", and click Apply button.
3. Restart your emulator.

Answer (score 3):

Accessing the In-App Developer Menu
When CTRL+M does Not Work In android Studio BumbleBee So open Terminal and Type (adb shell input keyevent 82) because in Android Studio BumbleBee I am facing this Problem

Comment: Yes! Same issue here!

Comment: You using Ubuntu or window

Comment: @kumail khan both `ctrl+m` and `adb shell input keyevent 82` do not work for me using Android Studio BumbleBee. it works if i press `d` or `r` in the metro bundler.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me
`adb shell input keyevent 82`

Answer (score 0):

Run this cmd `adb shell input keyevent 82` in terminal to debug when the app is running.